# Can member variables/methods/getters and setters be wrapped up in one common access modifier?

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax, access-modifiers, curly-braces

Is there a way to declare a bunch of members with one common access modifier? I do believe this can be done in C++ and some other languages, curious if it exists in AS3 though.

Instead of:

```
class FooBar {
   public var theDog:String = "Bark!";
   public var theCat:String = "Miao!";

   private var myBird:String = "Chirp!";
   private var myPig:String =  "Oink!";
}
```

It could be written as:

```
class FooBar {
   public {
     var theDog:String = "Bark!";
     var theCat:String = "Miao!";
   }
   private {
     var myBird:String = "Chirp!";
     var myPig:String =  "Oink!";
   }
}
```

Comment: Also, what's the name of this feature?

Answer (score 6):

I think you can write:

```
private var str:String, i:int;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wish, but sadly, the Flash/Flex compiler has no such shortcut (which I really miss when defining a chunk of static members).

Comment: For reference, see the reply made by Senocular the Great (Trevor McCauley - currently a Flash Player Quality Engineer at Adobe) http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?334406-From-here-on-out-make-them-all-static-public-private...&p=2498968&viewfull=1#post2498968